# Cannot use import statement outside a module-javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm a self-study student and having "Cannot use import statement outside a module-javascript" error
So, im trying to import hello() from hello.js..

```
///////////hello.js///////
export default function hello(){
    console.log("hello")
}

////////////app.js/////////
import hello from "./hello"
hello()
```

Comment: What environment are you even using (nodejs, browser, something else)? Please show us how you load/call the `app.js` module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import` and `export` require script type set as module to work, unless you transpile it. Try this :

```
<script type="module" src="app.js"></script>
```

which is equivalent to:

```
<script type="module">
    import hello from "./hello"
    hello()
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using modules or mjs files in a browser environment and for that you just need get the syntax right.

Say you have an x html page and you want to import a module there:

```
<script type="module">
    import { hello } from "/hello.mjs"
        hello();
</script>
```

And export the module you want to use in your x html page as such:

```
export const hello = hello;
```

Comment: *"So, im trying to import hello() from* **hello.js..** *"*. OP does not use `.mjs` file extensions. Your answer might not work.

Comment: I have said, "I am assuming you are using modules mjs file extension in a browser environment" and if that is correct, my suggestion works. If you are saying otherwise, you need to provide more context to your question.